# Running a zip file downloaded from Github with Python

Tags: python, github

I have a python 3 project on github, and I would like users to be able to download the zip file from the repository and run the program like:

```
$ python3 downloaded-file.zip
```

There is a __main __.py file and this works well when I zip the files up locally on my computer. When I download the zip from Github however, python is unable to run it with the error

```
File "downloaded-file.zip", line 1
  PK
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in the terminal. If the files are then unzipped, they can be run perfectly fine from the folder, but the .zip is easier for users to use. I would like it to be easy to download and run the python code and I'm not sure where the problem is arising.

Comment: uh, a zip file is basically binary garbage. it's **NOT** python code, so what exactly are you expecting python to be able to do with that garbage?

Comment: Since python 2.6, you can zip up a set of python files and the interpreter will look inside and execute __main __.py, referred to here [link](https://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/05/21/python-zip-files/). I have tried this by zipping up the files locally and it works, I just don't know why it doesn't work with the files zipped by Github.

Comment: can you provide a link to the zip file on github?

Comment: Sure, [link](https://github.com/mmmckay/geneparser/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `setup.py` for your package, that is the recommended approach for python pkg distribution.

and If I were you, I will publish it so that others can do `pip install pkg_name` too.

This is not a elaborate answer, But, I think You have got the gist

Comment: I will give this a try, but the code is more of a one-off use than a tool a user would use a lot within python. But is this is the best way to distribute it I'll try it out